# How can I debug a hanging java thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, tomcat

I have the following problem:
I deploy a web application in Tomcat (Linux) and after shutdown of Tomcat, if I do `ps -ef` I still can see the `java` process running.
I believe this happens due to some hanging thread but I don't know how can I track this thread down.
How can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate 4-5 thread dumps as described below and then analyze them using tools like [Samurai](http://yusuke.homeip.net/samurai/en/index.html).

What you want to check is when a stuck thread or long running transaction happens, all the thread dumps will show a certain thread id is at the same line in your java stack trace. In simpler terms, the transaction is spanning across multiple thread dumps and hence needs more investigation.

Now when you run these through [Samurai](http://yusuke.homeip.net/samurai/en/index.html), it will highlight these in Red colour so you can quickly click on it and get to the lines showing issues.

See an example of this [here](http://jojovedder.blogspot.de/2009/01/app-server-high-cpu-or-low-threads.html). Look at the Samurai output image in that link. The Green cells are fine. Red and Grey cells need looking at.

**Generating a Thread Dump:**

**(Linux)**

If the JVM is running in a console then simply press `Ctrl-\`.
If the JVM is running in the background then send it the QUIT signal:

`kill -QUIT process_id`

There process_id is the process number of the running Java process. The thread dump will be sent to wherever standard out is redirected too.
You can generally get the process numbers of of all running Java processes with the command:

`ps axf | grep java`

Comment: Its not that Jim is asking for, He is asking for debugging approch.

Comment: @aviad:I did a `kill -3` and loaded the javacore to Samurai.There was no visual table just a log report.How can I trace the thread from this report?

Comment: you open the dump log in samurai (using File->Open menu) find the problematic line in the stack trace that belongs to your code then try to figure out what went wrong/go to IDE, nail it with the break-point and debug your application.

Comment: @aviad:I have loaded the file, but I don't see an option to switch to IDE display.It is opened like a text file

Comment: I think that Samurai is analysis tool - you have to debug the code in IDE separately.

Comment: @aviad:I get the javacore.txt and loaded it using Samurai. It shows me exactly the same information I would see if I used e.g. `notepad`. Why?Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @aviad:There is 1 tab.But there is no name.It is like a textpane

Comment: then something is wrong :( try to figure out how to run the Samurai but if you do not manage in reasonable time - no worries just go over the dumps and look for correlations that refers to same line in your code. Then analyze/debug this line ...Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

You say your java process still exists, right?
Processes exist as long as they have attached threads, right?
If so, I would go for the following approach:
 - run the process with the MBean server attached and managed internally by the JVM

Then connect to the process after you send the QUIT signal and get the thread dump (there should be a JMX for that. See which threads look suspicious to you.

I think you can also use JVisualVM to take thread dumps...

Comment: I don't know how to do the approaches you recommend

Comment: This looks even easier, but it was already suggested by aviad :) : http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/basics/java-thread-dump.jspx

Comment: As for the JVisualVM approach - here is a tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/threads.html. Basically jvisualvm is just an executable file that can be found in $JAVA_HOME/bin folder... run it, connect to your application and see what you can do with it. Quite powerful stuff, really :)

Comment: How can I connect using `JVisualVM` remotely to my tomcat in linux installation?

Comment: Also how can I load a javacore.pid.txt using `JVisualVM`?